# server uploading error in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, server

i uploaded my project to server but it shows error like this can any one help??
i done project in codeigniter

**Strict Standards: require_once() [function.require-once]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CST/-6.0/no DST' instead in /home1/bijujame/public_html/domain.com/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 58

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONST in /home1/bijujame/public_html/domain.com/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 58**

Comment: @BIBINJOHN Then it's not smart having his domain in your comment for security reasons. But agreed he should not have the full domain posted here either.

Comment: @killstreet, right man...  dear sooraj s pillai, hide your domain details for security

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to do that,thanks for rembering me .

Answer (score 0):

A fix for your problem could be updating your index.php with the following line:

```
if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
   date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}
```

Ofcourse change the timezone to the one prefered.

Answer (score 0):

if you are from india

```
if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
}
```